# xml schema validation change from CXF 2.7.14 to CXF 3.1.8

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, cxf

I have created a CXF webservice. From WSDL and wsdl2java I have generated java class, in particular I have this enumeration:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="PType">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:enumeration value="P" />
    <xsd:enumeration value="P2" />
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

The webservice works well but I need to have schema validation. 
With CXF 2.7.14 when I call the method with a wrong value of the PType (ex. P3), I have as a result:

```
<soap:Fault>
  <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
  <faultstring>Unmarshalling Error: cvc-enumeration-valid: Value 'P3' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[P, P2]'. It must be a value from the enumeration.</faultstring>
</soap:Fault>
```

if I update CXF version to 3.1.8 when I call the method the result is that CXF convert the field PType to null and I don't have the unmarshalling error.

All the the code is exactly the same in both cases...how is possible? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, my endpoint contains <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" />

Comment: Setting unknown enum to null is the default behavior of JaxB. Did you tried to send en empty mandatory field ? Just to check schema validation is correctly enabled.

Comment: Yes, I tried, and I had an Unmarshalling Error (correct). I saw this issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-5722 . By the way is not possible to have the previus behaviour?