# Apache CXF enable schema validation for enum values

Tags: validation, enums, null, schema, cxf

I'm using Apache CXF (v3.5.0) to create a SOAP webservice.

The webservice was created from a wsdl which has some enumeration definitions like this

```
<xs:simpleType name="Status">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="Accepted"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Rejected"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

A java `enum Status { ... }` is generated as expected.

When sending a request with a correct value ('Accepted' or Rejected') everything works fine. Nevertheless, when sending an incorrect value the `Status` is `null`.

It makes sense to be `null` if the request schema is not being validated but when the `schema-validation-enabled` is active I would like to have a validation error rather than a `null` `Status` which may cause a NPE later.

I have both `schema-validation-enabled` and `schema-validation-type` set to true *(although the latter I'm no sure what it does)*

I know that the schema is being validated because I have validation errors in other situations (e.g. if I send two times the same field when repetitions are not allowed for that field)

Does anyone know how can I have this such behavior?

*This other question seems to tackle the same issue and points to a change in behavior in more recent versions of CXF, but it was asked 5 years ago and had no solution: [xml schema validation change from CXF 2.7.14 to CXF 3.1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40769143/xml-schema-validation-change-from-cxf-2-7-14-to-cxf-3-1-8)*